# Use the value of next row in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have this table with the following data:

```
ID  NUM1    NUM2
A   1000    1001
B   1001    1004
C   1006    1007
```

I want an out put like this :

```
ID  NUM1    NUM2    NUM3
A   1000    1001    1001
B   1001    1004    1006
C   1006    1007    1007
```

Could you please help me in achieving this.

Comment: how do you determine the correct sequence?  by ID or Num1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `LAG/LEAD` function in Teradata but you can rewrite it:

```
select ID, NUM1, NUM2
   coalesce(min(NUM1) -- next row's value
            over (order by ID
                  rows between 1 following and 1 following)
           , NUM2)    -- or current value when there's no next row
from tab
```